# Generating prime numbers of the form $\lceil \pi \cdot n \rceil $

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms

How to prove the following claims ?

Let $b_n=b_{n-1}+\operatorname{lcm}(\lceil \pi \cdot n \rceil , b_{n-1})$ with $b_1=1$ and $n>1$ . Let $a_n=b_{n+1}/b_n-1$ .

1. Every term of this sequence $a_i$ is either prime or $1$ .
2. Every prime of the form $\lceil \pi \cdot n \rceil$  is a term of this sequence.
3. At the first appearance of each prime of the form $\lceil \pi \cdot n \rceil$ greater than $7$, it is the next prime of the given form after the largest prime that has already appeared.

Implementation of this generator in PARI/GP can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwljEEKwzAMBO9-RY5S69BKV6E_5AuWccHEcYLr_D8xuczCwE5V_oozUhJX8r_rQGwp9AQok_vtDVZlX72xGr1L3CCmXGDJrxW9EUpQ44_RTDK-x9lhrA8od9Z4VI6W66NRLq7jIrc=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279929/are-there-an-infinite-number-of-primes-of-the-form-lfloor-pi-n-rfloor) is tangible related.

Comment: source of problem ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I made it by myself.

Comment: @PeđaTerzić How far did cou check the sequence ? In particular, which is the smallest prime that has not yet appeared ?

Comment: $1.$ is true upto $n=3\cdot 10^5$

Comment: It seems that if $p_n:=\lceil \pi\cdot n \rceil$ is prime then $a_{n-1}=p_n$. This holds upto $n=10^4$.

Comment: @Peter I must admit that I checked the third claim only for the first hundred primes of the form $\lceil \pi \cdot n \rceil$.

Comment: @PeđaTerzić What about arbitary primes ? Does $a_n$ contain every prime, not only the special ones ?

Comment: @Peter I don't know.

Comment: $a_{n-1}=p_n$ from above holds upto $n=10^6$

Comment: 2. is true as long as $b_{n-1}$ is coprime to the prime. After step 2 it is equivalent to: $$b_n=b_{n-2}\cdot (a_{n-2}+1)+lcm(\lceil \pi\cdot n\rceil , b_{n-2}\cdot (a_{n-2}+1))$$ a few steps later you'll be able to replace the $b_{n-2}$ values with $a_i$ value expressions. At that point, the sequence  created for a values, is nearly self contained.

Comment: How did you make this by yourself? You just played with recurrence relations and plugged $\pi$ inside and after that you realized that this produces primes (or $1$)? You can't be that lucky.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas I was inspired by [Cloitre's prime number generator](https://oeis.org/A135506).